# Question getting closed for being a duplicate when it's not?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions, reopen-closed

I had [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60237319/how-to-use-the-like-operator-to-return-data-in-arabic-in-sql-server) getting closed for being a duplicate. I don't consider it a duplicate at all. I wasn't asking what the N stands for in SQL but why is the Like operator not returning what I expected. Of course had I known I missed the N, I wouldn't have asked the question **plus** I wouldn't have found the other question because it wasn't going to be something I was going to search for because I already know what N is used for. I don't know what I don't know.

The question was closed by a single person. Not a group who shared the same opinion. I asked the person who left the useful comment to leave it as an answer so I can credit him. He can't leave an answer.

What's your opinion? Was marking it a duplicate and closing decision valid?

Comment: Wait for what and when? The duplicate explanation was there which I didn't agree with.

Comment: There's no reason to wait for anything, but there is a reason to assume good faith. Just because you disagree with another user's assessment that a question is a duplicate doesn't imply that they are abusing anything. Furthermore, [you already got an explanation from the close voter before posting this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60237319/#comment106574067_60237319), so acting as if you have no idea why he voted that way is somewhat disingenuous. It's fine to ask for a second opinion, but let's leave the implicit accusations of bad faith and foregone conclusions out of it.

Comment: and I am fed up with what happens on SO. Many people share the same sentiment. Many blog posts were written about this. It's an abuse when one person closes a question. Too much power.

Comment: Closing questions as duplicate does not mean the question is bad. It's closed as dupe so it can act as a signpost to an answer. That's not a bad thing.

Comment: It is straight up *not* abuse when one person closes a question. That's an ability we provide to users who have demonstrated their competence in a particular subject by the mechanism we use to determine competence: upvotes. Someone exercising the powers that they are given by the site, and using them to help reduce duplication and otherwise keep it clean, is the polar opposite of abuse. That blog posts have been written about something is not evidence of anything.

Comment: @Cody I don't like questions being closed by one person. He read my comment where I asked the commenter to leave it as an answer so I can credit him. The closer didn't wait for this to happen but decided to close it anyway. I and you don't have to agree about this.

Comment: Then make a feature request (there might already exist one).

Comment: @Modus I don't know the link and too busy to find it. I had a feature request before and people shot it down and the post just degraded. I am interested in going through a similar experience now. I am moving on. I am just ranting for what happened. 
I am sticking to all the comments I posted here. I don't agree with the closing. I I don't agree with the explanation. I don't agree with allowing one person to close a question regardless of their reputation. I didn't like that he didn't wait for the answer to be posted. All in all, the situation wasn't warranted.

Comment: No one needs to wait for an answer to be posted. The whole point of closing a question as a duplicate is to prevent the answer being posted over and over again.

Comment: *"where I asked the commenter to leave it as an answer so I can credit him."* If you want to credit someone, upvote the person that posted the answer on the question that yours is a duplicate of.

Comment: @Larnu This has very little effect. It's not all about giving credit to a comment. It's not the same as a question showing in the search result with an accepted answer or even an answer. It will show as a question with no answers which means most users won't bother to check out the question not realizing there was a comment that had an answer. 

Too bad that a lot of people do not realize this side effect. Closing questions quickly sometimes kills a question which could have been useful to future users.

Comment: How does upvoting an answer to another question yours is a duplicate of have little effect? It has a great effect, it shows how useful that answer is. This is why some answers have 100's of upvotes. The site can't force you to vote, but not voting for an answer that is useful (in this case solved the problem) does against the aim of the site, so I can only suggest that you don't understand it's goals. This does seem, I'm afraid, more clear considering your question here. Dupes are important, and having lots of them of the same question doesn't help the community reach its goal.

Comment: Personally, I see your question as a typographical error, if not a dupe. You forgot the `N` in one place, where as you had used it in another. Answers to typographical errors arent helpful to the community as their just typos. If the fact is that you didn't understand the implications of the `N` then the dupe explains that and you have your answer. In both scenarios a close is warranted; typographical errors are off topic and dupes can be closed as there is already an answer. Closing your question is a win win for you in both those cases as you have your answer.

Comment: @larnu Upvoting a comment has a lot less effect than posting an answer. Users do not see any kind of indicators of upvoted comments in search results but answers do. While I did say I wanted to credit the commenter, I wanted to do so as an answer.

I don't find someone who missed the N prefix in an international context, especially Arabic where letters display differently depending on their position in the word, to be a dupe of someone who doesn't know what the N prefix is or how it's used. The way people search for these two types of questions are different. Sorry but I don't agree.

Comment: I never said up vote a comment, I said upvote the answer. You've not read my comment... *"If you want to credit someone, upvote the person that posted the **answer** on the question that yours is a duplicate of"*

Comment: *". I don't find someone who missed the N prefix in an international context, especially Arabic where letters display differently depending on their position in the word, to be a dupe of someone who doesn't know what the N prefix is or how it's used."* Then it's a typographical error, and your question should have been closed as such. You out the `N` in one place, and forgot it in another. As you say you know what the `N` stands for you know that missing it out is a typo, and those are off topic for SO. That leaves you defending that typographical errors are on topic for SO..?

Comment: @larnu But I don't believe and don't agree the other question is a duplicate so why on earth I would upvote the answer on the other question!? I searched for 'Arabic' and 'Like' and the other question didn't show up. I won't search for N because it's NOT in my mind. I am missing it. That's the whole point. It seems people are too focused on the N prefix. I am focused on the Arabic language and its syntax. The other question has ZERO mention of 'Arabic' and therefore will never come up in the search. If my question was a dupe of the other, then BOTH should come up in the search.

Comment: No one here knows Arabic and how complicated its syntax and grammar is. I get it.

Comment: Let's make something clear here, the problem you were having had nothing to do with Arabic, it's language or the syntax or grammar of said language.

Comment: The person closing my question as a duplicate pointed to their own answer that was posted years after mine and merely had 5 upvotes.  A total abuse...

Answer (score 21):

Yes, the question is a duplicate. The closure is correct. The answer to your question is contained in the other question. When two questions have the same answer, they are duplicates.

You claim:

> If I knew I am missing the N, I wouldn't have asked the question! Two very different contexts.

The first part of this is certainly true, but irrelevant. Closing a question as a duplicate is *not* an attack, not a dismissal of the question, and does *not* carry any implication that you should have never asked the question.

Rather, questions get closed as duplicates by subject-matter experts who can see relationships and commonalities even when others with less experience cannot. It is a way of linking your unanswered question with an existing Q&A that already provides the answer. In some cases, seeing that link does require some expertise, or even assume that one already knows the answer to the question. That isn't a problem, and doesn't make the duplicate closure incorrect.

Context is not particularly important. That you arrived at the need to use/understand the 'N' prefix differently is true enough, but you still need to use the 'N' prefix. Even you agree with that, after reading Tim Biegeleisen's comment. All that matters is whether the answer to your question can be found in the answers to the other question. The goal of this site is to find an answer, after all.

There would be no advantage in having your question remain open with an answer posted by Tim Biegeleisen or anyone else that said "use the 'N' prefix on your Unicode string" over having your question marked as a duplicate of an existing, canonical question that explains what the 'N' prefix is, when it should be used, and why it provides support for Unicode characters in strings. At a minimum, they are both equally useful. In general, the latter is far more useful than the former because it groups related information together in one place, making it easier to find and curate. It also provides a greater depth of explanation than a one-off answer might.

You could argue that the answer to use an 'N' prefix with your LIKE operator should itself contain a link to the other question, which would then serve the goal of providing context and additional information. While that is certainly an acceptable approach, I do not see how it provides any advantage over closing the question directly as a duplicate. In either case, you get your answer. Closing it as a duplicate reduces pointless duplication and repetition. It also allows the solution to be more easily kept up-to-date (e.g., if future releases of SQL Server introduce an 'NX' operator that provides similar functionality with better performance or whatever).

Comment: Read my comment in the question about the question was also about the Arabic language. Users who know Arabic might propose better ways to do what I wanted to do. I can't get any such answers now the question is closed. I am pretty positive that none of the users who know Arabic is going to add to the other old question if they have a  good suggestion since the other question had nothing to do with Arabic.

What if the N prefix didn't answer my question or was it closed because I mentioned it solved the issue?

Comment: @Tony_Henrich *What if the N prefix didn't answer my question* --> edit your quesiton to highlight this and vote to reopen, as simple as that.

Comment: @Temani Meanwhile I have to maybe wait for days or ever for them to reopen it because someone didn't make a good decision. NO.. it's not simple.
Maybe I will just delete it and open a new one. A lot faster and cleaner.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich If you have a different question where the `N` prefix does not resolve the issue then yes open a new question, in this case though  you provided specific code where adding the `N` prefix does give your desired results. There is no need to keep open an example from every language on the off chance that someone has something specific to add about that language. But even if that premise is accepted it is still a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27091536/sql-arabic-search - which is both about the `LIKE` operator and arabic

Comment: @Tony_Henrich Deleting your question and reposting it? That would go against SO policy because it would be an attempt to circumvent how SO works. Just edit it - it will be reviewed in the reopen queue.

Comment: I'm happy to review and reopen it if you edit to explain why adding 'N' is not a solution to your question. I'm also happy to enforce the rules by issuing a suspension for deleting and reposting an identical question. So...your choice. It is generally better to work within the system than against it. It is still not clear to me why you are so upset about having gotten a working solution to your problem.

Comment: *I have to maybe wait for days* --> even if it's a week, time doesn't matter. Your question is *one* among plenty of other questions and a lot of them are voted each day for reopen. There is no reason to make yours a priority. You have to follow the rules and consider the fact that you are *probably* wrong.

Comment: @ModusTollens. Not posting the same question of course. What's the point if there's a high chance it's going to get the same treatment.

Comment: @Temani Time of course matters to me. I post a question for my own use which is my priority. I want an answer now. Not in a few days. It may be useful to future users. That's an added benefit and it enriches SO. I don't post questions just to make SO better. I don't work for them.

I am posting a new better question. There's no priority here. It's not going into any kind of queue. I am not trying to jump ahead of anyone by posting a new question. If you think I am posting a new question to be ahead of anyone, your assumption is wrong.

Comment: *Time of course matters to me. I post a question for my own use which is my priority. I want an answer now.*--> sorry but we don't really care about *your* priority and the fact that you want an answer *now*. I guess you are missing the purpose of SO that's why you think everyone is against *you* but there is no *you* and *me* here. There is only content.

Comment: @temani Well I value my time and I am sure most users do.  You should say 'I', not 'we'. Don't talk on behalf of others. Talk about yourself only. I post a question that benefits me and other users. That's content.  Anyway, I got my answer from the question before the question got closed. I just wanted to state my opinion. No one needs to agree with it. Discussing this further with you and others is pointless after I have posted several comments so far already.